# Formula for the entries of a matrix power.

Tags: matrices, reference-request

If $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with entries over an arbitrary field and $a_{ij}^{(m)}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-entry of $A^m$, with $m \ge 2$, then a straightforward proof by induction reveals that
\begin{equation}
    \label{ijentryofmatrixpower} 
    a_{ij}^{(m)} = \sum_{k_1,\dots,k_{m-1} = 1}^n \left[ \prod_{\ell = 1}^m a_{k_{\ell-1},k_\ell} \right],~k_0 := i,~k_m :=j.    
\end{equation}

I have seen this result cited in papers and alluded to in textbooks, but have never seen a proof for it. Is anybody aware of a reference for the result? (To reiterate, I realize the result is not difficult to establish, but it would be nice to be able to point to a reference.)